# how to build a lift chart using scikitplot

Tags: machine-learning, python

I am trying to build a lift chart using scikitplot library.

I am getting the following can anyone guide with the error.

please find the code with the error

CODE:

```
import scikitplot as skplt
actual = df['Actual']
predicted = df['Pred']

skplt.metrics.plot_lift_curve(act,pdt)

Error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-f14ae9c16143> in <module>
      6 pdt = np.array(predicted)
      7 # plotLiftChart(actual,predicted)
----> 8 skplt.metrics.plot_lift_curve(act,pdt)
      9 # plt.show()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scikitplot\metrics.py in plot_lift_curve(y_true, y_probas, title, ax, figsize, title_fontsize, text_fontsize)
   1192 
   1193     # Compute Cumulative Gain Curves
-> 1194     percentages, gains1 = cumulative_gain_curve(y_true, y_probas[:, 0],
   1195                                                 classes[0])
   1196     percentages, gains2 = cumulative_gain_curve(y_true, y_probas[:, 1],

IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

please guide where I have done the mistake

Answer (score 2):

The mistake is not to have read [the documentation](https://scikit-plot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/metrics.html) ;)

> `scikitplot.metrics.plot_lift_curve(y_true, y_probas,...)`
>
> Parameters:
>
> - `y_true` (array-like, shape (n_samples)) – Ground truth (correct) target values.
> - `y_probas` (array-like, shape (n_samples, n_classes)) – Prediction probabilities for each class returned by a classifier.

The second parameter `y_probas` should be a double-dimension array of the predicted probabilities for every class, not a single dimension array of the predicted class.

You can also check the example provided in the documentation which contains:

```
y_probas = lr.predict_proba(X_test)
```

Comment: Thank you Erwan Can you help me how to interpret the results

Comment: @PavanKumar Sorry I'm not familiar with these curves, but you can ask a new question.